# Listing the number of rows with 2 of 4 cells filled from a row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet, flatten

Imagine I had a sheet like this

```
People    Alpha    Bravo    Charlie    Delta    Echo    Foxtrot
p1        x                            x
p2        x        x        x
p3                 x                   x        x
```

etc.
How could I make a function that printed the number of people who took 2 of the following: Alpha, Charlie, Echo and Foxtrot

AKA one of these permutations:
A & C,
A & E,
A & F,
C & E,
C & F,
E & F

### Heading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:G = "x"; A2:A&"♥"&B1:G1; )); "♥"); 
 "where Col2 is not null"; ))
```

### update 1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B16<>"")*(E2:E16<>""))
```

[image]

### update 2:

```
=QUERY(INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 IF(B2:C="",,B1:C1&","), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(D2:D, "- D2$"), D1&"2,", IF(D2:D="",,D1&",")), 
 IF({E2:E, G2:K, M2:O}="",,{E1, G1:K1, M1:O1}&","), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(P2:P, "- Z$"), P1&",", ), 
 IF(Q2:Q="",,Q1&",")}),,9^9))), ",$", )), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1)''")
```

[image]

Comment: A few problems with this in the context I'm applying it in. I'm applying directly below where the sheet is, meaning there's a circular dependency, which i believe i fixed by changing the range. In addition, the input isn't always the same, is there any way I can change it for this? Thanks.

Comment: @Timewarper can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YOl1Ud-wAgjquaFfwSnRpLlcdC2PDBe2Cvw8Fz_XSVs/edit?usp=sharing

This is not the original sheet to protect the identity of those on it, but this is what is looks like. The values in the main block are not predictable.

Comment: @Timewarper see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11IFNA5zwskBkqjkSi-2s6RumY2fU2TA5A2Q6D4JV5kY/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thanks. However, I believe it is still not returning collect values for the lower two columns ( the choose 2 from 4 ones).

Comment: @Timewarper replace * to + if you want OR logic instead of AND logic

Comment: Thanks. Manages to turn a variant of this with an IF statement into a solution for the problem I was facing.

Comment: Now, this might be a little off-topic but it is still related to the graph and may have some shared logic with the question. Is there any way i could print the probability of any combination of groups, preferably all the combinations in the sheet and ordered by probability? For example A -> apple, carrot, dragonfruit. And is there a way, if theoretically all groups had fig, I could remove fig from the list. So Fig isn’t listed in combinations since all have it. I can presiding this or the function could find it. Sorry if this is a bit much to ask, I can make a new question if you wish.

Comment: @Timewarper so you want comma-separated headers sorted in descending quantity order excluding the common header. is that right?

Comment: Yes. There may be multiple common headers though. I would also like the frequency of each stated as well, if possible, please.

Comment: @Timewarper can you edit your sheet and include example of desired result?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZKaRtj5W1sBgaR3anXHDrEhb8mFCJP2Oorwo7U5U48k/edit?usp=sharing

Used a new sheet which shows data more accurately.

Comment: @Timewarper see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19yu41yLMlomO2wllAlxKy1jcLe11Bar7Jct41pHhiW4/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm indebted to you and your hard work. I can upvote and mark your answer as answered if you update your post with the thing from the first spreadsheet.

Comment: @Timewarper updated

Comment: docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/… Is there any way to do frequency of groups (listed at A22) with example output of what groups would come out for W2 (but output as frequencies instead) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the cell values are `x`:

```
=((B2="x")+(D2="x")+(F2="x")+(G2="x"))=2
```

If the cell values are checkbox(`TRUE`):

```
=(B2+D2+F2+G2)=2
```

Comment: Is there any way I can make this into an array which returns the total number of rows where the first formula is True?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(ArrayFormula(((B2:B="x")+(D2:D="x")+(F2:F="x")+(G2:G="x"))=2),TRUE)`

Comment: Is there any way to change it so that the input is random and unknown (not "x" every time)? Tried doing COUNTA but didnt work, maybe it clashed with ArrayFormula?

Comment: Simply replace `"x"` with `"your input"`.